# Codeigniter 3 Stripe Webhook Signature Failed

Tags: stripe-payments, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a subscription based script in codeigniter 3. The checkout session is beign created successfully with the function below :

```
private function create_checkout_session($type = "monthly", $productID, $metadata = array()) {
        if (!$productID) {
            die("Missing product ID");
        }

        if ($type == "monthly") {
            $mode = "subscription";
        } else if ($type == "yearly") {
            $mode = "payment";
        } else {
            $mode = "payment";
        }

        // Set your success and cancel URLs
        $success_url = 'https://xxxxxxx.com/memberships';
        $cancel_url =  'https://xxxxxxx.com/memberships';

        // Initialize the metadata array
        $metadata_array = [];

        // Process the metadata from the $metadata variable using foreach loop
        foreach ($metadata as $key => $value) {
            $metadata_array[$key] = $value;
        }

        try {
            $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
                'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
                'line_items' => [[
                    'price' => $productID, // Replace with your product price ID
                    'quantity' => 1,
                ]],
                'automatic_tax' => [
                    'enabled' => true,
                ],
                'metadata' => $metadata_array, // Set the processed metadata array here
                'mode' => $mode,
                'success_url' => $success_url,
                'cancel_url' => $cancel_url,
            ]);

            // Redirect the customer to the checkout session URL
            redirect($session->url);

        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
            // Handle any errors that occur during the session creation
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

After i fill all the details in test mode with example cards 4242 4242 4242 4242 the webhook always fails and returns me invalid signature.

This is my webhook function :

```
public function stripe_webhook() {
    $endpoint_secret = 'we_1Nbi11111111111111';

    $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $event = null;

    try {
      $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
      );
    } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
      // Invalid payload
      echo '⚠️  Webhook error while parsing basic request.';
      http_response_code(400);
      exit();
    }
    if ($endpoint_secret) {
      // Only verify the event if there is an endpoint secret defined
      // Otherwise use the basic decoded event
      $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
      try {
        $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
          $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
        );
      } catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
        // Invalid signature
        echo '⚠️  Webhook error while validating signature.';
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
      }
    }

    // Handle the event
    switch ($event->type) {
      case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
        // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        break;
      case 'payment_method.attached':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
        // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        break;
      default:
        // Unexpected event type
        error_log('Received unknown event type');
    }

    http_response_code(200);
}
```

I checked multiple times the test key and webhook id. Im lost and not sure how to debug further the issue.. Can anyone give me some ideas?

I was expecting the webhook to work after following the stripe documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $endpoint_secret = 'we_1Nbi11111111111111';

That doesn't look like the right format for that variable so that is probably not the right secret so the signature verification fails.

The secret is an ID like `whsec_xxxx`, you get it by clicking the "Reveal" button on the Stripe Dashboard page for a webhook.
[image]